# Error in read feed url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery function to read feed url. It is working fine if I use the other feed url. Please let me what is wrong in feed url.I'm using the feed url.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var resulta="";
$.get("http://feed43.com/6782621036337143.xml", function (data) {
alert(data);
  $(data).find('item').each(function(i){

    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
        var container = $(this).find('description').text();
        var img_url = $('img', container).attr('src');
        var url = $(this).find('link').text();
 var suffix='<span class="read">....<a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" >    
  →&nbsp;Read&nbsp;More</a></span>';
        var container=container.substr(0,800).replace(/\s+?(\S+)?$/g, '')+suffix;

  resulta+='<div class="narticle"><div class="atext"><h2 class="title">
  <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" >'+title+'</a></h2></div>
  <div class="new_content">'+container+'</div></div>';

   });
  $("#new_article").html(resulta);
```

Comment: Did you split the concentenated string with a linebreak just to make the code fit the window here, or is it like that? Open the console (F12) and see if there are any errors.

Comment: it is showing no error . code is working if i use other feed url.

Comment: Well, I'm pulled over by javascripts same-origin policy when I test it, so I'll assume that is the issue, unless feed43.com is your site ?  -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mJbq/8/)

Comment: Does your `alert(data)` show the expected data?

Comment: no.It is showing nothing

Comment: no feed43.com is not my site. please let me know how can I do it

Comment: Log the request, and see if it produces a same-origin policy error then.

Comment: how I can fix this same-origin policy error?

Comment: If there is such an error, you can't! Normally you're not allowed to use javascript to fetch data from other websites, as it is a security risk. There are two exeptions, one if the data is JSONP, the second if the API is especially set up to allow it. A workaround would be Yahoos YQL service, and the best option would be to get the data on the serverside, if the issue is in fact cross-domain policy problems of course.

Comment: k.If i use the other feed url i.e using site url. it is working but it is showing only 10 result I want to show more.